# need to highlight the outside <li> element when clicked inside li elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I have a listitem

in a view. Inside that one more ul is there. whenever i click on the inside li elements i need to highlight the outside

element. Please help... I tried htmlhelper but didnt worked

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Settings
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Destination", "Destination")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report", "Report")</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>                                 
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: you mean you have ul inside one of the li right

Comment: Please paste your full code here, this is an HTML issue not related to MVC